# Structuremap ObjectFactory.GetAllInstances inserts null value into list

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, structuremap

I have a very simple list I am instantiating with Structuremaps ObjectFactory.GetAllInstances().

```
private List<UserReleaseTime> _UserReleaseTimes = 
    ObjectFactory.GetAllInstances<UserReleaseTime>().ToList()
```

UserReleaseTime looks like this:

```
public class UserReleaseTime
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public double totalReleaseTime { get; set; }
    public double withinReleaseHours { get; set; }
    public double outsideReleaseHours { get; set; }
}
```

After the collection is created it appears that structuremap adds one object with empty or null values. Is there anyway to stop this from happening?

**Update:**
UserReleaseTime is registered with Structuremap like this:

```
For<UserReleaseTime>().Use<UserReleaseTime>();
```

Comment: Please show your configuration. How is that collection of `UserReleaseTime` registered in StructureMap?

Comment: I dont think its related to how I am registering the class. It seems to be happening anywhere I use ObjectFactory.GetAllInstances().

Comment: Are you injecting instances into the container somehow?

Comment: No not that I can tell. Its really just a simple basic setup going on.